# Using rollup watch to see changes in common/shared library and rebuild

Tags: npm, rollupjs, monorepo

I have a mono repo with `components` and `embedded` package.

I'm using npm workspaces for the mono-repo.

How do I ensure that when files in `components/src` change, rollup in `embedded` picks up those changes and rebuilds?

Root `package.json` snippet:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:components": "npm run build -w components",
    "build:embedded": "npm run -w components -w embedded build",
    "dev:embedded": "npm run -w embedded dev",
    "dev:components": "npm run -w components dev",
    "dev": "npm run --workspaces dev"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

Packages:

```
$ ls packages
components  embedded
```

`components` `package.json` snippet:

```
// packages/components/package.json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -cw",
   },
```

`embedded` `package.json` snippet:

```
// packages/embedded/package.json
  "scripts": { 
        "build": "rm -rf build && rollup -c",
        "dev": "rollup -cw",
  },
```

`components` `rollup.config.js`:

```
// packages/components/rollup.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'rollup'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'
import styles from 'rollup-plugin-styles'

export default defineConfig([
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      // I don't think we need both of these. Keeping them since we had them for now in webpack
      {
        dir: 'dist/esm',
        format: 'es',
      },
      {
        dir: 'dist/cjs',
        format: 'cjs',
      },
    ],
    plugins: [typescript({}), json()],
    external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'styled-components'],
  },
  {
    input: 'src/index.css',
    // assetFileNames helps us keep a consistent name to be imported by packages that use components
    output: [{ dir: 'dist/', assetFileNames: '[name][extname]' }],
    plugins: [styles({ mode: 'extract' })],
  },
])
```

`embedded` `rollup.config.js`:

```
// packages/embedded/rollup.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'rollup';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import styles from 'rollup-plugin-styles'
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve'

const preactAlias = alias({
  entries: [
    { find: 'react', replacement: 'preact/compat' },
    { find: 'react-dom/test-utils', replacement: 'preact/test-utils' },
    { find: 'react-dom', replacement: 'preact/compat' },
    { find: 'react/jsx-runtime', replacement: 'preact/jsx-runtime' },
  ],
});

export default defineConfig([
  {
    input: './src/recipe-explorer.ts',
    output: { dir: 'build', format: 'umd', name: 'recipe-explorer.js' },
    context: 'window', // needed to shut up react-share@4.4.0 `this` has been rewritten to `undefined` warnings in the output. You can safely remove this if you want garbage in the build output
    watch: {
      clearScreen: false,
      include: 'node_modules/components/src/'
    },
    plugins: [
      preactAlias,
      nodeResolve({ browser: true }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript(),
      styles(),
      replace({
        preventAssignment: true, // recommended to be set by library to make forward compatible,
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
        // ...
      }),
      copy({
        targets: [
          { src: 'src/index.html', dest: 'build/' },
          // { src: ['assets/fonts/arial.woff', 'assets/fonts/arial.woff2'], dest: 'dist/public/fonts' },
          // { src: 'assets/images/**/*', dest: 'dist/public/images' }
        ]
      }),
      serve('build')
    ],
  },
]);
```

I'm running `npm run dev:embedded` from root and it only picks up changes from `embedded` repo.

Comment: Is `components/src` part of the module graph for `embedded`? May want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373804/rollup-watch-include-directory